# How can I see HTTP headers triggered by web browers (Firefox, Chrome, Safari) in the exact same order they are built

Tags: google-chrome, http, firefox, safari, http-headers

I need to know exactly in what order HTTP headers are sent from my browser (whatever it is - I tried Chrome, Firefox and Safri with the same results).

The intent is to build a scraper that will mimic not only the User Agent of these browsers but also the browser "fingerprint".

I can use Wireshark to see but it is not always quick to use.
I would love to have this order available through a Dev Tool embeded in browser but headers are reorganized alphabetically.

See below HTTP headers as they are constructed by the browser (sniffed with Wireshark)
[image]

And then, what the Dev Tool from Firefox is telling me
[image]

Do you know an quick way to get this information? Is there an option to activate in Dev Tools preferences? An add-on already available?

Thank you for your time,

Comment: Check out [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: Thanks pfx, I'm already using Charles as a proxy debugger but daily use can be a bit annoying with HSTS mecanism for example when scraping SSL encrypted pages. I was thus looking for an browser "in house" solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I find a little tip with Firefox.

By building a new query from the previously sent, with the Web Developper tool, Firefox is displaying headers as they were send over the wire.

Quite handy!

See below - headers are now displayed in their real order (not alphabetical one)
[image]